# Mixing Ajax and Html Beging Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have my shared layout like this:

```
 <div id="bodyForm">

            @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="modal-price" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-price-label" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
        <div id="divReplacment" class="modal-dialog dialog-width-80-xs">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span>Loading....</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal-referalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="modal-price-label" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
        <div id="divReferalReplacment" class="modal-dialog dialog-width-80-xs">
            <div class="modal-content modal-color">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>@SelfServiceResource.SignUpTitle</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Action("_ReferalForm", "Home")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Inside second modal i have Ajax.BeginForm, and inside Body i have one Html.BeginForm.
Ajax works brilliant, but if when i submit my Html.BeginForm i got a source code of page, not View - source code.
What is my Problem?
Of course i have return View inside Post action for Html.BeginForm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question as I wasn't able to view the contents of *second modal*, therefore, there can be many reasons why its not working. Here are a couple of reasons from what I was able to interpret:

1. Syntax error.
2. Nested forms. HTML doesn't allow for nested forms (check [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) for flow content). Maybe this is causing an error somehow?

If you can provide the contents of the *second modal*, we can help narrow down the cause of the issue.